# INT to Binary and then read bits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an INT value in my database, which is actually storing the selected days of the week.

For example, `65 = 1000001`

Which would mean:

```
1:Sun
0:Mon
0:Tue
0:Wed
0:Thu
0:Fri
1:Sat
```

So then, I need to land up with a small temp table with:

```
DayOfWeek:
Sunday
Saturday
```

So, read the INT, and output a table of days.

Can this be done in SQL Server?

Comment: in DB and SQL, joining is always better than decoding. You only have 128 combinations, if I were you I would rather use a reference table.

Comment: means in output, you only want day which have 1 value, right? Also explain **65 = 1000001** , how this combination work?

Comment: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_unsigned_int.html?decimal=054053

Answer (score 4):

```
; with tbl as
(
    select  col = 65    union all
    select  col = 3
)
select  *
from    tbl t
    cross apply
    (
        select DayOfWeek = 'Sun' where col & 64 = 64    union all
        select DayOfWeek = 'Mon' where col & 32 = 32    union all
        select DayOfWeek = 'Tue' where col & 16 = 16    union all
        select DayOfWeek = 'Wed' where col &  8 =  8    union all
        select DayOfWeek = 'Thu' where col &  4 =  4    union all
        select DayOfWeek = 'Fri' where col &  2 =  2    union all
        select DayOfWeek = 'Sat' where col &  1 =  1
    ) d
```

Comment: Was writing an answer with basically this, so +1 instead. The `all` in `union` is unneeded :-)

Comment: @Jcl, it's actually needed as it removes the need to check for duplicates.

Comment: `union all` does not check for duplicates (`union` does)... actually, this should be faster with `union all` now that I think of it

Comment: @Jcl, that's what I've been saying. The all in the union removes the need to check for duplicates.

Comment: Wow... tat's fantastic @squirrel - looks perfect.

Comment: Hi Squirrel, could you explain how where col syntax work and the logic behind this

Comment: `&` is bit wise AND. Example `4` is `100` in binary. If the 3rd bit is 1, when perform bit wise AND with `100` the result will be `100` else it will be `000`

Answer (score 0):

Do not decode in SQL, it will be a pain after to use them.
If you have the number stored, you just join with a table like:

```
Code     Pattern
64       Sun
96       Sun-Mon
```

Or you can do that if you want per line

```
Code     Pattern
64       Sun
96       Sun
96       Mon
```

It is even better.

Otherwise you will have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

in DB and SQL, joining is always better than decoding if sill you need .

create an table like

colname    value

Sun              |    1

Mon              |    2

Tue              |    4

Wed              |    8

Thu              |    16

Fri              |    32

Sat              |    64

Join the data with the table and sum up the value ...